# connect ETIMEDOUT error using POSTMAN with NEWMAN

Tags: timeout, postman, newman

I'm using Newman in order to execute a POSTMAN collection but I always have the
error  "connect ETIMEDOUT". Using just POSTMAN it works fine, but not with NEWMAN.
The testing is quite simple,  create a content on the server
 **https://jsonblob.com/api**

I'm following the tutorial
http://blog.getpostman.com/2014/04/17/how-to-write-automated-tests-for-apis-with-postman-part-2/

Thanks you very much in advance. I put below the collection and the enviroment file.

**This is the collection:**
{
  "id": "a6a6b2fe-db11-4c57-9144-6b3324174f18",
  "name": "Newman",
  "values": [
    {
      "key": "url",
      "value": "https://jsonblob.com",
      "enabled": true,
      "type": "text"
    },
    {
      "key": "deviceMapping",
      "value": "{\n  \"content\": \"My first blog post :)\"\n}",
      "enabled": true,
      "type": "text"
    },
    {
      "key": "blogLink",
      "value": "https://jsonblob.com/api/jsonBlob/b7f2ce87-4c8e-11e8-917b-9137e61d314b",
      "enabled": true,
      "type": "text"
    }
  ],
  "_postman_variable_scope": "environment",
  "_postman_exported_at": "2018-04-30T16:13:07.630Z",
  "_postman_exported_using": "Postman/6.0.10"
}

**This is the enviroment file:**
{
  "id": "a6a6b2fe-db11-4c57-9144-6b3324174f18",
  "name": "Newman",
  "values": [
    {
      "key": "url",
      "value": "https://jsonblob.com",
      "enabled": true,
      "type": "text"
    },
    {
      "key": "deviceMapping",
      "value": "{\n  \"content\": \"My first blog post :)\"\n}",
      "enabled": true,
      "type": "text"
    },
    {
      "key": "blogLink",
      "value": "https://jsonblob.com/api/jsonBlob/b7f2ce87-4c8e-11e8-917b-9137e61d314b",
      "enabled": true,
      "type": "text"
    }
  ],
  "_postman_variable_scope": "environment",
  "_postman_exported_at": "2018-04-30T16:13:07.630Z",
  "_postman_exported_using": "Postman/6.0.10"
}

Comment: What have you tried so far? What requests do you have in your collection? How are you running Newman? etc You're going to need to update the question with a lot more information. I would also recommend reading this and change your tests as that blog is quite old now - http://blog.getpostman.com/2017/10/25/writing-tests-in-postman/

Comment: Hello. Thanks you for your answer.
Well, I'm sending a request of the type POST to the IP https://jsonblob.com/api that would create a new content in that service.
I'm runing NEWMAN with the console CMD, going to the folder where the collection is stored and using the command: "newman run  Testing.json" but I have used as well
"newman run --delay-request[300000] Testing.json" but I have the same problem.
I will see the link that you have put. Thanks you very much again.

Comment: Is there a reason why you have a 5min delay between the requests? How many requests do you have?

Comment: I have two request, a POST to create the content and a GET to get this one. There is not a reaso because I put this time out  in particular. 
Thanks you again and best regards.

Comment: Are you saving the 'location' to an environment file like in the tutorial? You haven't added this to your Newman CLI arg if you are. Also  `newman run --delay-request[300000] Testing.json` this shouldn't really work either as the first argument should be the 'collection' file and not a arg flag.

Comment: Hello. I'm storing the 'location' in a variable called 'blogLink'. How could I add this to the Newman CLI? Please. Thanks you again.

Comment: It should be saving that 'location' value to the environment file, as per the tutorial that you're following - This file fills in the `{{...}}` placeholders like the request URL base path etc. In the UI, you would select the file from the dropdown list but for `newman` you to need to supply the path to it. So you CLI arg would be something like:  `newman run <your_collection_file.json> -e <your_env_file.json>`

Comment: I have had the same connect ETIMEOUT error with that CLI. I have added the collection and the enviroment file to the question, I hope it can helps. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What version of newman and node do you have - It doesn't look like its a Postman specific issue with the files (might be wrong) but it seems more environmental. As I don't know what your set up is, it's difficult to help further and it shouldn't really be done in the comments section anyway.

Comment: Hello, my Newman version is 3.9.3. Sorry if I'm not asking it in the right place, if there is another way much better, I will do. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed: It was a proxy matter. I wrote these two commands in the cmd console:

```
set HTTPS_proxy=myuser:mypassword@ipoftheproxy:portoftheproxy
set HTTP_proxy=myuser:mypassword@ipoftheproxy:portoftheproxy
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a proxy issue for me, I added my organization specific proxy in Postman settings and it worked.

Answer (score -1):

Fixed by change the proxy protocol

For Mac User

1. Go to Settings -> Network -> Advanced -> Proxies
2. Tick "Auto Proxy Discovery"
3. Click "Ok"
4. Click "Apply"
5. Restart Postman
   [image]

Another way:

1. Go to Postman Settings
2. Set SSL certificate verification to off

Let me know if you found any issue

[image]